# ActionBarSherlock menu item is too big

Tags: android, size, actionbarsherlock, menuitem

I'm using ActionBarSherlock, everything is fine, but one user reported, that menu item is too big on his Galaxy S3 phone. This is what he sees, portrait:

[image: portrait]

landscape:

[image: landscape]

normal view from my device:

[image: normal view]

item list xml file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/refresh"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/refresh_text"
        android:titleCondensed="@string/refresh_text">
    </item>
</menu>
```

menu inflating code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbar_itemlist, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: post your code for the icon/menu bar also what phone do you have ? (want to know if screen is bigger)

Comment: have you got the image in all your drawable folders (i.e) are you providing support for `xdpi , mdpi, ldpi etc...` screens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your comments it is clear you need to have the image in all the drawable files

```
drawable-xdpi
drawable-hdpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-ldpi
...
```

As your image is a standard android icon image you can just look where you found that image and you should be able to find the icon you need.

This is required as different phones have different size screens and by having a image for every size screen the correct one with correct dimensions is used. So problems like the image being too big or too small wont happen. It is also in general good android practise so I advise you to utilise the folders. (theyre there for a reason!)

You can download the android stock icons (and all the version xdpi, mdpi etc...) from [here](http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

I've just experienced this problem too when preparing my app for launch, and for me it was down to the fact I'd misinterpreted the icon guideline's sizes and had all my xhdpi icons at 98px or something, just make sure that all your xhdpi icons are 64x64. If you don't have a separate draw able folder for xhdpi screens then that'll be your problem as samsung s3 is xhdpi([screen sizes](http://androidresolution.blogspot.nl). Just make a drawable-xhdpi folder and put the 64x64 images in there.

Comment: I have only one image in `drawable` folder, can I somehow make it fixed without creating a new images?

Comment: I'm guessing this one image is the refresh drawable, you will need to create new images for different screen sizes if you want your app to look the same on different devices. It's not hard though, you should be able to use http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-actionbar.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=ic_action_example&theme=light&color=33b5e5%2C60 to generate them as long as you give it a large enough image to scale down.